# Error starting groovyserver \Groovy\Groovy-2.3.3\bin\.. was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, groovy

I have just downloaded and installed Groovy 2.3.3 using the Windows installer. While trying to run some of the examples using `groovyclient` (which tries to start `groovyserver`), I receive the following error.

> `\Groovy\Groovy-2.3.3\bin\..` was unexpected at this time.

My `Groovy_Home` is as follows:
`GROOVY_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-2.3.3`

The full output is as follows:

```
C:\Users\Greg>groovyserver     
Groovy home directory: "C:\PROGRA~2\Groovy\GROOVY~1.3"
Groovy command path: "C:\PROGRA~2\Groovy\GROOVY~1.3\bin\groovy.bat" (found at GR
OOVY_HOME)
\Groovy\Groovy-2.3.3\bin\.. was unexpected at this time.
```

I am running on Windows 7 Home Premium - 64 bit

Comment: Same problem here, with Groovy 2.2.1 Have you resolved the issue by any chance?

Comment: I just reinstalled Groovy on one of my machines outside of the `Program Files` directories and I can now run the `groovyclient` and `groovyserver` without an issue. I'll check on my other workstations and see if it helps. Can you verify if this works for you as well? If it does, I think we have an answer.

Comment: That worked for me as well. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is a universal solution but here's what worked for me on two separate machines running Windows 7 Home Premium (64) and Windows 7 Enterprise (64).

I tried this out with both Groovy 2.2.1 and Groovy 2.3.4

I simply uninstalled Groovy and installed it again, this time outside the `Program Files` directory. The `groovyclient` and `groovyserver` tools started working properly and I no longer get these errors.

Apparently, Groovy has some trouble running the executables if they're installed in `Program Files`. I'm not sure why this happens. I suspected that it may have something to do with spaces in the catalog's name but I successfully ran `groovyclient` installed in such a directory ( `C:\Groovy\Test groovy with spaces\Groovy-2.2.1` specifically). Therefore, I suspect this has something to do with permissions.

If anyone has an idea why this happens, feel free to expand upon this answer. Maybe the exact reason this error occurs is different and I just managed to work around it by changing the installation directory.